# PHP mail() usando XAMPP sin que se abra la configuración de correo de windows

Tags: php, html, email, xampp

Estoy intentando mandar un correo a una determinada cuenta usando PHP a través de un formulario web en el que el usuario pone su nombre, correo electrónico y el mensaje en cuestión. Mi intención no es usar PHPMailer, sino simplemente usar mail().

La idea es que desde el correo del usuario, se mande un correo con el mensaje y nombre escritos en el formulario, a la cuenta de correo de contacto de la Web. Adjunto el formulario:

```
<form id="contacto" class="footer" action="formValidation.php" method="post">
                        <div class="row">
                            <div class="col-sm-12 myContainer">
                                <input type="text" id="nombre" name="name" placeholder="TU NOMBRE" />
                            </div>
                        </div>
                        <div class="row">
                            <div class="col-sm-12 myContainer"> 
                                <input type="email" id="email" name="mail" placeholder="TU EMAIL" />
                            </div>
                        </div>
                        <div class="row">
                            <div class="col-sm-12 myContainer">
                                <textarea "id="msg" name="msg" placeholder="TU MENSAJE"></textarea>
                            </div>
                        </div>
                        <div class="row">
                            <div class="col-sm-12 myContainer">     
                                <button style="cursor:pointer;" class="button buttonF" type="submit">Enviar</button>
                            </div>
                        </div>
</form>
```

El código PHP que utilizo es lo siguiente:

```
<?php
htmlspecialchars($_SERVER["PHP_SELF"]);

$name = $_POST['name'];
$email = $_POST['mail'];
$msg = $_POST['msg'];

$to = 'correoDestino@dominio.es';

if (isset($_POST["submit"]) && $_SERVER["REQUEST_METHOD"] == "POST") {
    $name = test_input($_POST["name"]);
    $email = test_input($_POST["mail"]);
    $msg = test_input($_POST["msg"]);
}

function test_input($data) {
    $data = trim($data);
    $data = stripslashes($data);
    $data = htmlspecialchars($data);
    return $data;
}


$cabeceras = 'From: ' . " " . $email . "\r\n";
$cabeceras .= "Content-type: text/html; charset=utf-8";

$msjCorreo = "Nombre: " . $name;
$msjCorreo .= "\r\n";
$msjCorreo .= "Email: " . $email;
$msjCorreo .= "\r\n";
$msjCorreo .= "Asunto: Formulario de contacto Web";
$msjCorreo .= "\r\n";
$msjCorreo .= "Mensaje: " . $msg;
$msjCorreo .= "\r\n";

if (mail($to, "Formulario de contacto Web", $msjCorreo, $cabeceras)) {
     echo "<script language='javascript'>
        alert('Datos recogidos, muchas gracias. Pulse aceptar para ver la información a enviar y proceder con el envío del email.');
     </script>";
} else {
     echo "<script language='javascript'>
        alert('fallado');
     </script>";
}

echo nl2br("Se ha enviado la siguiente información:\r\n");
echo "Nombre: " . $name;
echo nl2br("\r\n");
echo "Correo electrónico: " . $email;
echo nl2br("\r\n");
echo "Mensaje: " . $msg ;
?>
```

He usado TestMailServerTool para ver si se enviaban los correos y aparentemente sí que se envían(se guardan en la carpeta de la aplicación). El problema que tengo, es que al enviar los datos del formulario se me abre la configuración de Windows para correos electrónicos(de Outlook concretamente):

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Lo que quiero, es que se mande el correo sin más, sin que el usuario en este caso tenga que configurar la cuenta en su propio ordenador. Simplemente que al dar al botón de enviar en el formulario, se envíe un correo automáticamente a la cuenta de destino con la información del formulario.

De esta forma podría comprobar si se reciben bien los correos y de la forma esperada.

Muchas gracias por adelantado, un saludo.

Comment: Repasa qué estás intentando hacer. Estás intentando enviar un correo hacia tu web desde una dirección ajena que no te pertenece simplemente con el nombre de la dirección. Se abre el el outlook porque habría que introducir la contraseña de dicha dirección, en caso contrario podrías usar cualquier correo que no te pertenece libremente ¿Por qué no haces que el formulario tenga otra cuenta de correo propia que te pertenezca y esta envíe el correo?

Comment: Mmm así visto tiene sentido. Pero en ese caso, podría usar la misma cuenta para enviar y recibir el correo(me supongo). Lo único que el correo estaría "duplicado" estando en enviados y recibidos.¿Podría hacer eso?

Comment: He probado esto que acabo de comentarte y veo que me vuelve a abrir el outlook para intentar configurar la cuenta de correo, pero la que estaba usando antes, lo cual ya si que no entiendo por qué es. Aunque cambie la cuenta que introduzco en el formulario, el outlook intenta configurarme la que comencé poniendo en su momento y el problema persiste a pesar de usar la misma como origen y destino :(

Comment: Veo que en esta otra pregunta el mensaje lo envía en ambos sentidos, pero no mencionan en ningún momento sobre la necesidad o no de configurar los correos.

https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18379238/send-email-with-php-from-html-form-on-submit-with-the-same-script?utm_medium=organic&utm_source=google_rich_qa&utm_campaign=google_rich_qa

Comment: Eso es porque en el propio script PHP no lo configuras, la configuración viene de fondo, y te aseguro que no hay problemas con enviarse correos a uno mismo. El tema de que se abra outlook puede tener que ver con la caché del programa, pero no debería preocuparte dado que una vez que configures el MAIL desde el servidor no debería volver a abrirse. https://www.quackit.com/php/tutorial/php_mail_configuration.cfm

Comment: Entiendo, entonces si no me equivoco ¿lo que tendría que hacer es configurar el php.ini de mi servidor para poner la dirección de correo que quiero en el sendmail_from? y así ya funcionaría aunque en el código PHP tenga la misma dirección para enviar que para recibir.

Comment: Acabo de probarlo cambiando el php.ini de xampp y veo que sigue pasando lo mismo. ¿Supongo que esto en el servidor oficial no pasaría puesto que está todo configurado verdad?

Comment: Creo que hay conceptos no muy claros en la pregunta.

Un usuario Pepe, con el correo "correoPepe@gmail.com" va a tu web de contacto y rellena los datos, diciendo que es Pepe, y que su email es correoPepe@gmail.com.

Este correo debe llegar a la dirección de email que TU poseas para leer los emails. Y entiendo que lo que quieres es que cuando recibes el email, en vez de recibirlo y ver "CGI-Mailer" o cosas similares, quieres ver "Pepe <correoPepe@gmail.com> como si él te lo hubiera mandado desde su propio email, facilitando así el darle a "responder" y que el correo le llegue al usuario

Comment: Estoy en lo cierto?
Porque de ser así... no hay misterio ninguno, ya lo tienes todo configurado con la variable $cabeceras

Comment: Hola buenos días, en teoría eso es lo que pretendo hacer sí. Pero al no poder acceder(de momento) al servidor donde alojaremos la web no puedo probarlo mas que en local. Uso XAMPP y Test Mail Server Tool como comentaba.

El problema es que se me abre outlook para intentar configurar la cuenta de correo electrónico y no se por qué. Así que intenté lo que hablaba con Juliosor de usar mi propio correo tanto para enviar como recibir la información, pero sigue saliendo la configuración de outlook.

En la carpeta de mails enviados del Test Mail sí que salen como intentos de envío sin configurar

Comment: Acabo de probar subiendo todo al servidor remoto y parece que funciona bien, se envían y reciben los correos. Muchísimas gracias por toda vuestra ayuda :)

Sólo tengo una última duda, el formulario parece que guarda los datos al usarlo desde el "index" únicamente. Al usar el formulario en una subpágina se envía/recogen los datos en blanco, y no se me ocurre por qué. El action para el código php en el index es action="formValidation.php" como se ve en la primera imagen de la pregunta. Y en el resto de páginas es action="../formValidation.php" ¿Eso no debería ser problema verdad?

Comment: La otra cosa que acabo de ver es que además, no hay saltos de linea en el mensaje recibido ya ponga "\r\n" o PHP_EOL. Me pone todo el msjCorreo seguido en vez de en líneas distintas.

Comment: Perdonad el "flooding" acabo de solucionar el primer problema, eran una " de más en el id="msg" del formulario. Ya me va el formulario correctamente en todas las páginas de la web. Pero sigo teniendo el problema de los saltos de línea, seguiré investigando a ver, pero de primeras no se me ocurre qué puede ser.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

El problema de que no se mostrasen los saltos de línea lo he resuelto cambiando en el código PHP, en el msjCorreo los saltos de línea PHP "\r\n" por la etiqueta HTML "< br>" puesto que el content type es text/html así que se recibe como html.